# Visual Studio: breakpoint excluding calls from a specific function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I want to set a breakpoint in unmanaged C++, in Visual Studio 2005, but I would like to ignore this breakpoint if the call stack is in a specific function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Oh....did you mean ignore the breakpoint if in a specific caller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a commercial edition of Visual Studio, you should be able to set a breakpoint early in the calling routine, then change its "When Hit..." behaviour to "Run a macro".  You'll need to write a macro that programmatically disables the breakpoint in the called function -- use this as the macro to run.  (Hopefully someone else can describe how such a macro can be written.)  Then set other breakpoints on all exit points of the calling function, and change their behaviour to reenable the breakpoint in the called function.

If you have an Express Edition, you'll find that the "Run a macro" checkbox is greyed out unfortunately.  In this case, if you have access to the source code for the calling function, I suggest the following:

1. Make a global `int` variable, `bp_enabled`, initially set to 1.
2. `--bp_enabled` on the first line of `calling_function()`.
3. `++bp_enabled` at all exit points of `calling_function()`.
4. Change the "Condition..." properties of the breakpoint in the called function to break only when `bp_enabled == 1`.  (Go to Debug | Windows | Breakpoints, then right-click the breakpoint.)

A bit of a hack, but it gets the job done.

**[EDIT: Fixed to work properly even if `calling_function()` happens to call itself recursively (either directly or indirectly)...]**

Comment: If you can change the code there should be easier ways to make this happen - but j's idea is good.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a [DebuggerStepThrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) attribute on the calling method, altho this will stop all breakpoints being hit on the calling method, rather than just the specific method

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** *OP initially didn't make it clear at the beginning unmanaged C++ was being used. So this answer is pretty useless now because it'll only work with managed code. That said I'll leave it be in case someone stumbles over it and finds it usefulor didn't know about JMC:*

Whilst `DebuggerStepThrough` is still a valid method to prevent stepping into code there are times when you do want to step in. This means having to locate and comment out the `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute.

.NET 2.0 introduced a new attribute: [`DebuggerNonUserCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute.aspx). This works in conjunction with the *Debug Just My Code* setting in Tools->Options->Debugging->General->Enable Just My Code.

If Enable Just My Code is checked then any method decorated with the `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute won't be stepped into. If you do want to re-enable debugging of code marked with `DebuggerNonUserCode` periodically then just uncheck this setting. This saves some time having to locate and comment out code you'd normally not be interested in stepping through.

To use either attribute just decorate the methods of your choosing like this:

```
// The .NET 1.1 way
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static void IgnoreMeAlways()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello...where is everybody!");
}

//The .NET2.0/VS2005/2008 way. Use in conjunction with Debug Just My Code
[DebuggerNonUserCode]
public static void NonUserCodeSomeTimes()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Longtime no see");
}
```

Comment: Yes...unfortunately. I guessed you may have been using managed C++

Comment: Sadly the last time I touched unmanaged C++ was in VS6, a long time ago, so I doubt I'll be much help :(

Comment: Cheers dewd....if I'd known it was unmanaged c++ I would never have bothered making all that effort to achieve minus 1 :)

Comment: Thinking about this - even with this feature I'm not sure how this helps the problem??

Comment: Ja....now I've re-read it a few more times and seeing j's answer I see what he means now.

Answer (score 0):

You could put breaks on all the lines that call your method in question (except in that one caller routine you don't want to stop). I can see this being difficult if the routine is called from a lot of places, or invoked in non-obvious ways.

Changing the code just for debugging seems like the easiest - if possible.